# Why would Voldemort break Lucius' wand if he wanted to borrow it?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

In the movie HP7 Part 1, Voldemort takes Lucius' wand in the dining room scene at the beginning of the movie.  He then breaks it and asks about the core.

> Voldemort: Do I detect Elm?
>
> Lucius: Yes, my lord
>
> Voldemort: (breaks wand) And, the core...

If he intended to use it, why would he break it?  From The Chamber of Secrets, we know that a wand that's been broken is never the same. Only with the Elder wand was Harry able to repair his.  Surely Voldemort knows a broken wand is useless.  Why would he have broken it, and how did he fix it?

I realize there is a difference between the books and the movies, and that this never happened in the books, so I know the books are useless to answer this, and the movies don't.  So that leaves us with JKR quotes.  Was this ever addressed?

Comment: Don't forget he is a jerk...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In the film he doesn't appear to break the wand. It looks like he separates it from the cane handle that Lucius had attached to the base of the wand.

Answer (score 40):

**harmingcola** is correct -- Voldemort detached Lucius's wand from the snake's head handle Lucius had affixed to it. He didn't break the wand; if he had, the wand wouldn't have worked correctly, which it did until Voldemort tried to kill Harry during the Seven Potters scene, at which point it shattered from the force of the magic from Harry's wand.

I have some images that support **harmingcola**'s answer.

[image: Voldemort takes Lucius Malfoy's wand]

You can see the silver base of the snake's head handle, holding Lucius's wand in place.

[image: Voldemort, about to break Lucius's wand]

The base is visible as Voldemort prepares to break Lucius's wand.

[image: The wand with the base still attached]

And, finally, the detached wand with the base still visible.

These images match **harmingcola**'s answer, so any upvotes should go to **harmingcola**.

Comment: Yep. That's pretty obvious now that I see your screen captures.  My only excuse (and I realize it's lame) is that I was watching this on a very low-res device at the time, and the silver base looked white on that device, and I thought it was the exposed wood. These pics make all the difference.  I respected your wishes, but I think you deserve *some* points for taking the time to get these. Are you sure I can't vote you up at least?  I already voted harmingcola's answer and accepted it. Voting you up would not detract from those points.

Comment: @DavidStratton - I don't think that's a lame excuse at all. We see all kinds of little details on a higher resolution screen than a low res device. For a few years I watched all my media on my computer. Then we got a good-sized tv. Holy cow, the difference is amazing. Weeeell, as long as you gave **harmingcola** points first, I won't object to one upvote. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for the support, much credit to you for putting in far more effort than i did

Answer (score 6):

I know this has been answered already, but I just wanted to add what I think Voldemort's reason for breaking off the wand handle is.

At this point, Lucius Malfoy has lost all favour with Voldemort, having failed him time and again, not to mention unintentionally and indirectly bringing about the destruction of the diary Horcrux. As punishment, Voldemort gave Draco Malfoy the job of killing Dumbledore, hoping that he would die in the attempt. In *Hallows*, Voldemort has taken over Malfoy Manor (seemingly using it as a Death Eater HQ), and Lucius is visibly a wreck. So snapping the grandiose snake's head off the wand handle is a way of emasculating Lucius even further.

Answer (score 2):

The book goes into a great level of discussion about the twin cores and connection between Voldemort's wand and Harry's, and V's search for a wand that would not suffer from this weakness (first, a borrowed Lucius's wand and more importantly, the Death Stick).

This was a movie-dramatization way of showing that Voldemort required a wand with a core that was NOT paired with Harry's - and was willing to go to great lengths -  without 5 minutes of dialogues and internal monologues that the book can afford.

Answer (score 1):

The wand isn't actually broken when Voldemort snaps it, he's just taking off the silly looking handle. As for asking about the core, he wants to make sure he has a wand that can beat Harry's, unlike what happened in the Goblet of Fire. :)

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to the site! Someone already gave the same answer, which I accepted as the right answer. I also clarified why I mistakenly thought the wand was broken in a comment on Slytherincess' answer. My lame excuse is that I'd been watching on a low resolution device and it looked different. Her pictures are a lot more clear than the picture on the 2 inch screen I was looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Voldemort didn't need extravagant design or any extra grandeur. He needed an efficient wand that would counter the twin cores effect. He also wanted to humiliate Lucius for his terrible performance as a Death Eater. Thus, he separated the wand from its handle, which is also the handle of Lucius' cane, and used it as a regular wand, without the grip.