# Do people normally own more than one wand?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

Is there any **canon** information in Harry Potter that proves one way or another whether a wizard always owns only one wand as a matter of routine?

What I am talking about is a wizard buying and owning one wand and also a second wand (for backup, or simultaneous use, or separate purpose, or ceremonial+work wand), akin to people buying more than one pair of boots, guns or hammers.

A proof would be either canon info showing someone owning 2 wands simultaneously; or a statement showing why that does not happen except in rare exceptions (see below).

---

NOTE: I am discounting special situations such as winning an extra wand in a duel ala Harry (e.g. the second wand's obtainment wasn't intended/planned), or someone winning a Death Stick from prior owner (in which case it was intended as a replacement wand and not an extra one); or taking another's wand for a time being, ala Voldemort and Lucius Malfoy (since it was more of a "temporary replacement because main wand was useless for the purpose due to paired cores" - far from a normal situation).

Also, I meant wands intended for use - e.g. if Malfoy would have a (imagined by me) collection of rare antique wands, that's as irrelevant as someone having flintlocks in a display case.

Comment: I picture some bad ass Auror with a vest full of wands a la Il Duche from Boondocks Saints

Comment: @Monty129 - I'm tempted to photoshop either [this](http://whysoblu.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/boondock-saints-il-duce-whysoblu.jpg), or Chau Yun-fat from [Replacement Killers](http://i.digiguide.tv/up/0808/32346-TheReplac-12191424412.55.jpg)

Comment: Great question. I had always wondered this since Olivander started saying things like "nice for charm work" or "excellent for transfiguration" about wands, which suggests a highly skilled wizard may well have a wand for each specialisation.

Comment: Charlie bought a new wand — perhaps if he hadn't had a younger brother he'd have had two simultaneously?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your mistake [for lack of a better word] is that you are viewing wands as a "hammer" or a "boot" of which someone can just have spares.

But remember that wands are exceptionally special to a wizard.

Firstly:

> ...Mr Ollivander states that a wand chooses a wizard....
>
> ...The second states the connections made between both wizard and wand are **complex**, and will grow with **experience**, the wand learning from the wizard, the wizard from the wand....
>
> *Wandlore page on [Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wandlore).*

Also, some further insight to the Wand phenomena is given [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8120/are-wands-in-harry-potter-sentient?rq=1).

Furthermore:

> ...a wizard may channel his energy with any wand, whether his or not. However, the best results come where there is a great likeness between a wizard and a wand....
>
> *Wandlore page on [Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wandlore).*

Generally the bond takes time to develop.

To me, the thing wouldn't be whether or not people do or don't have multiple wands, as we know this *is* possible, but the issue would be how *well* the wand is used.:

[Would the Elder Wand choose every new owner who wins?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51967/would-the-elder-wand-choose-every-new-owner-who-wins)

[Can a Person Be Chosen By More Than One Wand?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24371/can-a-person-be-chosen-by-more-than-one-wand?rq=1)

[Can a wizard use more than one wand?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18498/can-a-wizard-use-more-than-one-wand?rq=1)

As you mentioned that a wizard could possibly have a wand for 'ceremonial' use. I believe this can be a fair possibility; have a main wand, which one is akin to, regardless of how it looks; and then have a nicely-adorned one like [Lucius Malfoy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23130/why-would-voldemort-break-lucius-wand-if-he-wanted-to-borrow-it/46350#46350)'s wand, which one could use during ceremonies and the like. 
Having said that, if you had a *main* wand, which you loved and were attached to - and vice versa - wouldn't you be proud to show *that* one off, regardless of how it looked?

Tactically, I believe it a possibility to have extra (or back-up) wands. But since the other wand is not going to be much more effective than say an umbrella lying about (if your main wand breaks during a duel); then why bother carrying an extra wand around?

Comment: ... because carrying a spare umbrella around is inconvinient? :)

Comment: But if all wizards only ever used a single wand, what happens when the wand is destroyed in some irreversible way? Or taken to some far away place? Wouldn't it be better for wizards to train with multiple wands to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: Uh-oh, did I just tell @DVK he's made a mistake?

Comment: @Mooz - Inconceivable!

Comment: @DVK `because carrying a spare umbrella around is inconvinient? :)` tell that to Hagrid!

Comment: So having two useful wands would mean wizard needs to use them both a lot, and would mean extra training, like gunslingers from Westerns training to use pistols akimbo. Could be a nice character for some HP future work.

Comment: Ask a professional blacksmith if their hammer is "just a hammer". And a blacksmith will own multiple hammers of different weights and shapes for different purposes, like a large one for moving a lot of metal, and a smaller one for detail work. And they would probably tell you that they have a close relationship with each hammer and know each one's personality intimately.

Answer (score 1):

In Pottermore, when you get your wand, it's mentioned that there are regulations by the Ministry for Magic regarding the purchase of wands. We don't know if one's allowed to purchase more than one wand, but at least we do know it's something the Ministry keeps an eye on.

Comment: `there are regulations by the Ministry for Magic regarding the purchase of wands` Really? Where does it say that?

Comment: @Möoz - https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Code_of_Wand_Use. Granted, in canon it is mentioned by name only in relation to Clause Three, but it seems it's more comprehensive than that.

Answer (score 1):

In *Deathly Hallows* Chapter 19 there is an example of a wizard carrying a backup wand, and he explicitly states that its purpose is to be a backup wand:

> "Did you just say you got away from the Snatchers with a spare wand?"
>
> "What?" said Ron who had been watching Hermione examining the locket.
>   "Oh – oh yeah."
>
> He tugged open a buckle on his rucksack and pulled a short, dark wand
>   out of its pocket. "Here. I figured it's always handy to have a
>   backup."

While it is true that Ron did not *deliberately* procure a backup wand, the fact remains that he had the backup wand for several weeks already.

Comment: Given Ron's history, having a backup wand was probably not a bad idea....

Comment: +1 for "I figured it's always handy to have a backup", shows he's at least thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the movie Order of the Phoenix, when Snape takes Harry down to start the first Occlumency lessen, he unrolls a tool belt, and seems to pull a wand out. Why would he be keeping his only wand stored away in a tool belt? Maybe I am wrong, but it seems that is what happened.

Comment: _"**seems** to pull a wand out"_...? Was it unclear? Also, the question asked about people, not just Snape. Even if Snape had a spare wand, it doesn't follow that others did.