# Do wizards need Muggles?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

I was just thinking, if some Dark wizard succeeded in a Mugglepocalypse - what then?

Are they just some extinct species of animal at that point or do Muggles have some value wizards would lose?

Comment: dark wizards dont want to kill all the muggles, they want to enslave the muggles.

Comment: ask a muggleborn ;) - in seriousness though, I think Hagrid's explanation to Hermione in book 2 re: "mudblood" as well as book 6 and the Gaunt family offer some ideas: namely, there really aren't entirely 'pure-blood' families and inbreeding is bad

Comment: As far as I know, Muggles invent all the stuff wizards steal later and add a little bit so they can claim it is "magical" - toilets, administration, architecture, trains, glasses, beds, cameras, music, motorcycles, carriages, British food, socks ...

Comment: @Himarm What's the point in enslaving muggles when you have obedient elves and magic?

Comment: There wernt enough elves for everyone first of all, second you still have to cook food despite magic molly is seen cooking for hours. As well as slave labor for growing food, building buildings just because you can magic something doesnt mean having a slave do it isnt more fun

Answer (score 68, accepted):

## It seems likely that wizards could handle total Muggle extinction.

While the total extinction of Muggles may cause wizards some problems, it seems likely that they'll be able to handle any problems it poses.

**There would be enough wizards for a minimum viable population so it's likely they'll survive.**

The reason the Gaunts were so deformed due to inbreeding is because they limited their choices to pure-blooded British wizards whose families were one of only a few British pure-blood families. Depending on the size of the wizard population they may become inbred like the Gaunts. If the wizarding populations are sufficiently small, they may be unable to avoid inbreeding, and either create offspring with genetic defects, or choose not to reproduce and die off. However, the global wizarding population likely contains enough members to prevent this. The global population of wizards is surely much larger than the number of respected pure-blood wizard families in Britain, and likely is large enough to provide the minimum viable population required to keep them from dying off.

Researchers have studied how many people would be required to create a stable long term population. Some suggest a number of 160 would be enough, but that figure is also questioned often and may not work. A number often cited as the *optimal* number of people needed to create a viable population without excessive inbreeding is somewhere around 5000. Another [study](http://www.popularmechanics.com/space/deep-space/a10369/how-many-people-does-it-take-to-colonize-another-star-system-16654747/) gives a higher number of 10,000 people, which the study says will ensure against both inbreeding and something killing off part of the population. While none of these numbers may be exact, once there are reasonably more wizards than this, it seems highly likely that they will survive. Even at the lowest number given by JKR math, there are more students in Hogwarts than 160, and that's just one school in Britain. The total number of wizards globally is surely much higher.

Humans have survived, and without widespread defects due to inbreeding, with fairly small populations, and until recently, very few ways of accessing other humans too far outside their own place of living. Also, [research](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20160113-could-just-two-people-repopulate-earth) has [shown](http://ice2.uab.cat/argo/Argo_actualitzacio/argo_butlleti/ccee/geologia/arxius/1Ambrose%201998.pdf) that human populations were very low at certain points in history. While scientists disagree about the exact numbers, they do agree that the human population was drastically lower, and are saying it may have been as low as [2000](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/science/nature/2975862.stm) individuals. The highest estimate given in that study for the population was around 10,000 fertile women. Even using that number as a baseline, the global wizarding population would have enough members to meet this requirement as well.

There are *at least* 100,000 wizards in the world, since that's the number of wizards Arthur Weasley, an employee of the Ministry of Magic, says would be attending the Quidditch World Cup.

> “The trouble is, about a hundred thousand wizards turn up to the World
> Cup, and of course we just haven’t got a magical site big enough to
> accommodate them all. There are places Muggles can’t penetrate, but
> imagine trying to pack a hundred thousand wizards into Diagon Alley or
> platform nine and three-quarters.” - *Harry Potter and the Goblet of
> Fire, Chapter 6 (The Portkey)*

That's just the number of wizards who are willing and able to attend the Quidditch World Cup. That doesn't account for wizards who don't care about Quidditch, or were busy, or had other responsibilities, or were too poor to afford going. The number in the total global population of wizards would be therefore at least somewhat higher, likely a large portion higher. After all, even though something like the Super Bowl is a very popular sporting event, only a fraction of Americans attend it.

**In addition, Muggles might not be necessary to manage the technology they'd leave behind.**

Sure, the Muggles might have created things like nuclear reactors, but while wizards probably wouldn't understand this technology, they could almost certainly dispose of it. They would have no reason to keep it around since they don't use Muggle technology. In addition, they wouldn't have to keep their disposal methods secret or hidden from the Muggles, since they'd be all dead. Wizards wouldn't be able to manage a nuclear power plant, but even if it took multiple wizards working together, they would be able to Evanesco it, or otherwise make it disappear.

Wizards might not expect the problems that unmanaged Muggle technology might bring, but even if they don't, they could likely still handle it. If some disaster starts happening, they could probably take care of it with magic. They'd be able to use the full force of their powers at any disaster they encounter, since they no longer have to be concerned with keeping their magic hidden from anyone. In addition, not all wizards are as unaware of Muggle technology as Arthur Weasley is. All it would take is one wizard (perhaps a Muggle-born like Hermione) who knows about nuclear reactors to tell the others, and get the problem handled.

Comment: I think this answer should be considered biased because of the source.  ;)

Comment: @Wildcard I'd have more reason to look into this than most. ;)

Comment: To succeed in ridding the world of Muggles only to find we needed them to survive would be foolish, we've thought out our plan well. ;)

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time someone stumbled over their own delusions of grandeur. :p

Comment: Given that most wizards are half-blood, as mentioned in the answer by @Mithrandir, there's no way to get rid of Muggles occasionally being born (squibs). If getting rid of Muggles includes getting rid of half-bloods, I think there'll remain much fewer wizards.

Comment: It's interesting to think of the Malfoys discovering that they suddenly need to become competent Farmers.

Comment: @Ruslan Getting rid of Muggles implies only getting rid of people without magical powers, so I defined "wizards" as "anyone who has magical powers" regardless of blood status. In addition, Squibs are quite rare, so while there may be an occasional Squib being born, there won't be that many.

Comment: Is their any source on the assumption that the only thing that wizards used muggles for was breeding stock? It definitely appears like magic had no limits, and that technology and manpower were completely useless to wizards, but is it ever stated like that explicitly? Are we certain that wizards do not use electricity or muggle produced food?

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski We see throughout the books that wizards don't use Muggle technology or manpower, most of them are isolated from Muggle society and wouldn't need either. It's less certain if wizards eat Muggle-produced food since there isn't as much information on food production as there is on general wizard life. I'd guess not on a large-scale basis since even very isolated wizard communities are able to get food, and many wizards would be incapable or unwilling to get food from Muggles. There are likely wizard farmers who are just never mentioned because they aren't relevant to the story.

Comment: Do wizards farm? Or magic food and water into existence? In sufficient quantities and with a decent enough distribution system to avoid mass famine? You're only looking at the least relevant datum here: whether they could maintain a healthy population in terms of genetic diversity. That is the least of their problems.

Comment: Fairly plausible, if wizards are willing to practice exogamy!(+1)

Comment: @terdon [Gamp's Law](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gamp's_Law_of_Elemental_Transfiguration) tells us that *someone* has to farm.

Answer (score 19):

For one, *wizards* might go extinct if they did that. There aren't enough wizards for them to survive without Muggles:

> “Most wizards these days are half-blood anyway. If we hadn’t married Muggles we'd've died out.”
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, chapter 7</sub>

If Muggles went extinct, that would be a very, very, very, large percentage of the world. It would essentially be removing almost all of the Earth's population. Think about it. Cities would be desolate. Wild animals would start moving around freely and not being kept under check. Creatures like dragons would be able to breed where once Muggles lived, because there would be no one living there. It would essentially be ridding the world of mankind and then the wizards would go extinct as well.

[Nuclear disaster would happen](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3621492/What-happen-Earth-humans-disappeared-Watch-terrifying-sequence-doomsday-events-unfold.html), because nobody is there to take care of things. This would cause nuclear fallout all over. This is pretty much a 'what would happen if humans disappeared' question, because once Muggles are gone, wizards won't be far behind.

To address what [@Bellatrix said](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/166702/33591) about simply Vanishing the nuclear reactors and stuff - I don't think they *know* about them. Most wizards have terrible knowledge of the Muggle world - take Archie in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* with the Muggle clothing and Arthur Weasly all over the series with knowing nothing about telephones and stuff. I don't think they would realize that things like nuclear reactors would cause problems, simply because they a.) don't know about them b.) don't know what they do.

> Harry, Ron and Hermione joined it, right behind a pair of men who were having a heated argument. One of them was a very old wizard who was wearing a long flowery nightgown. The other was clearly a Ministry wizard; he was holding out a pair of pinstriped trousers and almost crying with exasperation. "Just put them on, Archie, there’s a good chap, you can’t walk around like that, the Muggle on the gate’s already getting suspicious –" "I bought this in a Muggle shop," said the old wizard stubbornly. "Muggles wear them." "Muggle women wear them, Archie, not the men, they wear *these*," said the Ministry wizard, and he brandished the pinstriped trousers. "I’m not putting them on," said old Archie in indignation. "I like a healthy breeze round my privates, thanks."
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire</sub>

Comment: Surely the wizards would mate with each other? Many wizards may normally date Muggles but if there's no-one else left...

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Ron explicitly says that they would have died off. You also run into interbreeding problems. But after a little while it won't matter, everyone will be dead from the nuclear reactors melting anyway.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the nuclear meltdown claim is an unsourced claim from the Daily Mail. It is likely highly overstated, and I strongly suspect many of them would go into some sort of safety mode and shut down.

Comment: *"Ron explicitly says that they would have died off."*  Glad to know that a twelve year old schoolkid's offhand commentary on global population dynamics is taken as authoritative.  ;)

Comment: FWIW it's possible that at some time in the past, there were few enough wizards in the world to effectively force them to intermarry with Muggles, even if that may not _currently_ be the case.

Comment: @wildcard - heh. Presumably he has *some* sort of backing for this - his family is a pure blood Wizarding family, so I suspect that the information came from *somewhere*.

Comment: Oh, it certainly came from *somewhere.*  Drunken ramblings from one of his many redheaded uncles?  :D  I'm quite certain Draco, another twelve year old schoolkid from a pure blood Wizarding family, would state exactly the opposite view—and his statements *also* came from somewhere.  So this is a very partisan answer: were this Politics.SE, you'd get torn to pieces (downvoted) for only citing the biased views of the side you already agree with.  :P

Comment: @Wildcard frankly though, I'm not sure whose authority I would trust less: a twelve year old, or the [Daily Mail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eBT6OSr1TI) annoncing some doomsday scenario...

Answer (score 13):

It is likely that wizards source the majority of their food supply from the muggle population.

> **Hermione:** "Your mother can’t produce food out of thin air, no one can.
>   Food is the first of the five Principal Exceptions to Gamp’s Law of
>   Elemental Transfigura—"
>
> **Ron:** "Oh, speak English, can’t you?"
>
> **Hermione:** "It’s impossible to make good food out of nothing! You can Summon it
>   if you know where it is, you can transform it, you can increase the
>   quantity if you’ve already got some..."

Comment: Too bad these quotes were contradicted by the other quotes in the books, where Ron's Mother makes food out of nothing. Also, "increasing the quantity" of food **is** making food out of nothing.

Comment: You should find those quotes, I seem to remember her doing stuff with food too. It would be interesting to see how well it fits with Gamp’s Law. That would be a good question!

Comment: @alex.common - already asked: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93306/how-did-molly-weasley-make-sauce-out-of-nothing-if-gamps-law-states-that-this-i - tldr - she isnt making it - she is likely just summoning it from somewhere or assembling existing ingredients

Comment: @GreySage my headcanon is that when you increase the quantity of a food, you don't increase its flavour, and perhaps don't increase its nutritional content. So, say you duplicate a loaf of bread, the amount of taste, calories, vitamins, etc in the initial loaf is now just spread over two loaves.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it would just make it much harder for them to operate in general... There aren't really enough wizards to run the whole world and an openly Wizarding community would be hard to keep from tyranny (squibs might be expected to be persecuted)

Also although they don't necessarily need muggles everywhere there are certain items (bread, goods) which are good enough from all sources.

Another opinion might be that industrialization is pointless before magic but it's actually hard to decide since the costs associated with the use of magic in general have never been clearly defined in the books.

**On Squibs**

Considering that currently, the non magical squibs can simply blend into the Muggle world, it is evident that they'd be ostracized *very heavily* if there wasn't a sizable population of Muggles.

Indeed it seems more than likely that they'd be treated like slaves or worse than animals as they wouldn't have any sort of technology.

Or alternatively one might suggest that it is possible that Muggles are in some sense the descendants of squibs.

Considering that being a squib is random, unless they were killed off or sterilized it's impossible to prevent the resurgence of muggles.

Comment: This is an interesting take.  It doesn't add *very* much to other answers present (please take the site tour; we're a bit different from a forum), but I'd like to see you expand on the tyranny aspect as that has not been brought up.

Comment: Done as suggested... @Wildcard..