# Could Muggles survive without wizards?

Tags: harry-potter

[Do wizards need Muggles?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166692/do-wizards-need-muggles)

This question got me thinking could muggles in the harry potter universe survive without wizards, if wizards died out for some reason perhaps every newborns is a squib, what would be the effect of this on the world of Harry Potter ?

I'm imagining that giants, dementors and the like would run amok ?

Would House elves take it upon themselves to protect the muggle world ?

Comment: How do you think [us Muggles](http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/) are alive now? :)

Comment: Oh i am sure not being constantly obliviated and allowed to research magical creatures and artifacts would enormously boost muggle science, dealing with giants etc. wouldn't be a big challenge. the problems that'd arise from the new knowledge gained kinda remind me of the Strugatsky brothers book 'The roadside picnic'.

Comment: I think that the dragons by themselves would be able to kill whole swathes of the population. Even wizards find them neigh-on impossible to subdue - and they have **magic**.

Comment: @thedarklord I guess it's a no then.

Comment: @TheDarkLord nah, they can be subdued by targeting the eyes. I bet the muggles would create a fashion line with items from dragonskin, dragons will be experimented upon and the muggles will exploit all the 12 uses of dragon blood (whatever they are) muggles are scary and would cause the dragons go extinct if they'll know about their existence.

Comment: @Nahiri Dealing with giants would probably be more of an exercise in diplomacy than in science.  As far as scientific approaches go, we have tanks.

Comment: I apologise for casting a close vote. It came up strange on my phone. @NKCampbell these two questions are most definitely NOT duplicates, they ask to very different questions.

Comment: ah - I misread the question. Retracting vote :)

Comment: hmm....would there be giants, dementors, etc...in a world without wizards? Are you talking about some sort of wizarding pandemic in the existing wizarding world or a speculative universe where everything in the Wizarding World as we know it is the same, except for the total, infinite, and from the beginning of time, absence of wizards?

Comment: @NKCampbell If wizards *and* all those other things don't exist, we may actually have a somewhat functioning example of such a world.

Comment: right @MishaRosnach - in which case, it's a weird, if not, useless question imo. If on the other hand, it is talking about 'The Wizarding World' with a total absence of wizards, it is unanswerable as it would be totally opinion based. The entire premise of the series on which you would be basing an answer assumes wizards have and always will exist...unless OP reframes the question to relate to "Fantastic Beasts" and the New Salem lot. Assuming they get their way and eliminate wizards - that's the only path I see the question being reasonably framed. But even then: muggle-borns may always exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found something that can explain how the Muggles are/were protected from the magical beings like dragons and dementors and such...

Can't believe I'm actually typing this but; in 1750, `Clause 73` was added to `The International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy`. Here is the mentioned clause:

> Each wizarding governing body will be responsible for the
>   concealment, care and control of all magical beasts, beings, and
>   spirits dwelling within its territory's borders. Should any such
>   creature cause harm to, or draw the notice of, the Muggle community,
>   that nation's wizarding governing body will be subject to discipline
>   by the International Confederation of Wizards. —Clause 73,
>   [International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them_(real))

**So, the wizarding community was under obligation to protect the muggle community in order to stay hidden and safe.**

It is a very necessary clause but it's been breached [repeteadly](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/International_Statute_of_Wizarding_Secrecy#Breaches_of_Clause_73).

There is no need to say that if the wizarding community didn't bother to protect muggles, muggles wouldn't survive. Not only the magical creatures would annihilate them but wizards like Malfoys and Tom Riddle would also try to erase them from existence.

Comment: "wizards like Malfoys and Tom Riddle would also try to erase them from existence" Except in the situation proposed by the question, there are no wizards like the Malfoys or Voldemort - there are no wizards, period.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Well, just ignore that bit then. That clause was added to the Statute in order to keep the muggles safe. Because they couldn't survive if the good wizards wouldn't be there to protect them.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more add you are quoting Wizard law

Comment: I don't think this implies that they're controlling them for our protection. Rather, it looks more like their doing it for their own. If we find a unicorn, we find magic, then we find them.

Comment: How did muggles survive before there were wizards?

Answer (score 2):

There is no definite answer to that possible, I think.

However, in my opinion, the impression I form from the books is that magic, while basis of the wizarding world [which in itself is a rather small in terms of quantity of wizards] was not that easily seen in the mundane world, *except when dealing with the result of miscalculations or malice by wizards*.

If we consider what we see described about Arthur Weasley's work, it is *mostly* to do with amok spells or magical items created *by wizards*. Yes, there are mentions also of wild magical creatures accessing mundane world, however, my impression was that just like ordinary animals, magical animals are more frequently avoiding humans.

And, starting from the second half of 20th century, and moreso now, I think, if magical creatures were not subtle enough, any massive outbreaks of attacks on humans would provoke investigations and some sort of mundane dealing with the magical problem, simply due to (population) size differences.

Dementors or other indirectly harmful magical beings might be subtle enough to affect lots of people without noticing, however, if we consider depression as magically induced, while substantial portion of people are affected by it, it is not as if we are completely helpless about it.

Additionally, while any particular magical creatures might be immune to some sort of human weapons (bullets, etc.), none of them in the JKR world seem to be immune to EVERYTHING.

Answer (score -1):

I feel like the muggles wouldn't survive without wizards in the Parry Potter universe, because wizards are known to be secretly helping them anyways. If we took wizards away from that universe, there would most likely be Chaos. From all the deadly magical things that walk the earth.

Comment: I think it's been established that a good old nuke is enough to solve most magical problems. There seems to be no shortage of nukes at this time either.

Comment: @Gallifreyan We can finally thank North Korea for something