# Is it possible to restore humanity in the world after Resident Evil Final Chapter?

Tags: movie, post-apocalyptic, resident-evil

In the Final Chapter, there are less then two thousand people remaining in the Earth. It seems to be a very small genetic database to produce healthy human beings (humans without hereditary diseases due to endogamy).

Cloning laboratories were destroyed by the "heroes" (if they can be considered heroes after killing innocent clones, including children).

Umbrella workers, members and its relatives, including children, were killed by "heroes" while in suspended animation.

Natural resources and fauna seem to be destroyed (like the infected crows and dogs) and new and dangerous species have appeared.

Even if the antidote was liberated in the final, what will remain to restart humanity? Will it be able to kill non human zombies?

To me it seems the "heroes" of the movies just want to shut down everything and wait for death.

Is it possible to restore humanity in the world after Resident Evil Final Chapter? And is this the objective of the "heroes"?

Comment: I wrote an answer about whether wizards could survive without Muggles, which has a lot of information about population dynamics. It's in reference to a different franchise but the statistics would be the same so you might find it interesting. [Do wizards need Muggles?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/166702/80602)

Comment: Wikipedia shows that a reboot is in the works... but either way, if it would make their parent company more money, humanity would find a way to survive...

Comment: If the first paragraph were on Worldbuilding, it might be closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3/2113).  While 2000 is small, it also means that there won't be as many genetic diseases.  Some won't appear in the 2000, particularly as the sickly are less likely to survive.  The [minimum viable population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_population) page on Wikipedia indicates that 500-1000 are enough.  With culling, you might be able to do better.

Answer (score 3):

According to National Geographic, the human population at one point was somewhere around 2000 individuals, and today we have 8 billion. So, yes, humans probably could survive once the massive hordes of bio weapons were taken out of the equation.