# Can you order a replacement wand?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore, hagrid

Hagrid keeps his broken wand. Breaking seems a mode of punishment and not just an inconvenience.

Can a wizard buy a new wand if the old one is broken?

Comment: See the related question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24371/ Can a Person Be Chosen By More Than One Wand?

Comment: The real question is: "Can you _order_ a wand (online, via telephone/floo network/owl), or do you have to purchase it in person?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It fully depends on the reasoning behind the breaking of the wand. Upon accidental breaking of the wand, a replacement can indeed be ordered. However Hagrid had his wand broken as a punishment for being expelled from Hogwarts. He is not allowed to practice magic as he never graduated.

I should also mention that he keeps his broken wand inside his umbrella and still uses magic.

Mentions of broken wands being replaced that I can remember are:

Neville Longbottom, he got a new wand after breaking his dad's old wand.

Ron breaks his wand on the whomping willow in CoS and gets a replacement by the PoA.

Comment: As an addendum, what was probably *not* shown was the presentation of official documentation when purchasing the wands at Ollivander's, because that would be boring to explain.

Comment: But what if the basis of the punishment was fraud? As the saying goes in the criminal justice and administrative & judicial world, which generally covers Hagrid’s penalty —  “fraud vitiates everything,” His wand was broken because he was framed by the universe’s worst villain; it was BS, and the “wand / magic world” probably accommodates that. If Hogwart’s had any sense of social justice, Hagrid should have gotten a full pardon long ago, with his wand fully restored or replaced, and wizarding instruction given at Hagrid’s convenience.

Comment: @SillybutTrue Exactly right. Not to mention there is no requirement to graduating in order to be able to perform magic. Wizards/Witches are perfectly allowed to be home schooled and still perform magic.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?  Ron got Charlie's old wand when he started at Hogwarts. One or 2 other examples are available. I expect wizards in good standing can purchase a new wand.

Answer (score 0):

Ron bought a new wand with the remainder of the Weasley's windfall after they visit Egypt in the Prisoner of Azkaban.

Answer (score 0):

#### Wizards can buy new wands once theirs wasn’t confiscated.

Wizards can get new wands if theirs is broken, damaged, or worn out, even if they previously had bought a wand that chose them. Ron gets his brother Charlie’s old wand, so presumably Charlie was able to buy a new wand easily enough.

> “You never get anything new, either, with five brothers. I’ve got Bill’s old robes, Charlie’s old wand and Percy’s old rat.’
>
> Ron reached inside his jacket and pulled out a fat grey rat, which was asleep.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 6 (The Journey from Platform Nine and Three-Quarters)*</sup></sub>

Charlie’s wand is not in a particularly good condition when Ron gets it, so it’s likely the reason he needs a new wand is because his old one is too worn to work as well as he’d need it to.

> “He rummaged around in his trunk and pulled out a very battered-looking wand. It was chipped in places and something white was glinting at the end.
>
> ‘Unicorn hair’s nearly poking out. Anyway –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 6 (The Journey from Platform Nine and Three-Quarters)*</sup></sub>

When Charlie visited the Burrow, he has a wand, so he was indeed able to get a replacement wand. Also, Ron couldn’t have given back his old wand because Ron accidentally breaks it in his second year.

> “The source of the commotion was revealed as they entered the garden and saw that Bill and Charlie both had their wands out, and were making two battered old tables fly high above the lawn, smashing into each other, each attempting to knock the other’s out of the air.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 5 (Weasleys’ Wizarding Wheezes)*</sup></sub>

Additionally, after breaking Charlie’s old wand Ron later buys a new wand, though that is the first wand he has bought.