# Is it possible for a wizard/witch to have two wands due to multiple personalities?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

So I was thinking about witches/wizards with two personalities (dissociative personality disorder/multiple personality disorder), and entertained the possibility of them being chosen by two wands. Do you think that it would be possible?

(Similar question "[Can a Person Be Chosen By More Than One Wand?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24371/can-a-person-be-chosen-by-more-than-one-wand?rq=1)" did not specify mental illness, so I think I'm in the clear with this one.)

Comment: At the end of HPDH, the title character had two wands.

Comment: Yup Harry had both his wands at the end (Granted his original one was broken at the time, but he repaired it using the elder wand)

Comment: We have no idea if multiple personality disorders even exist in the Wizarding World. If this question hinges on mental disorders to make it not a dupe it might be to opinionated/dupe.

Answer (score 5):

### We have no cases of this, so we don't know.

All cases of wizards with any form of mental disorder, or psychological condition are shown to either not have wands, or to have had their wands taken away. If a wizarding child had multiple personality disorder they would most likely be in St. Mungo's or kept watch in their own homes.

We already know that Wizards can be chosen by multiple wands so adding in multiple personalities doesn't really change this possibility, but it most likely limits the wizard or witch from receiving a wand at all.

Professor Lockhart is locked up as we see here - due to losing his memory

> “Listen to him,” said the Healer, taking Lockhart’s arm and beaming fondly at him as though he were a precocious two-year-old. “He
>   was rather well known a few years ago; we very much hope that this
>   liking for giving autographs is a sign that his memory might be coming back a little bit. Will you step this way? He’s in a closed ward, you
>   know, he must have slipped out while I was bringing in the Christmas
>   presents, the door’s usually kept locked . . . not that he’s dangerous!
>   But,” she lowered her voice to a whisper, “bit of a danger to himself,
>   bless him.

Neville Longbottom's parents were tortured to insanity - they share the closed ward with Lockhart and others.

> “My son and his wife,” she said, turning haughtily to Harry, Ron, Hermione, and Ginny, “were tortured into insanity by You-Know-Who’s followers.”

Finally, Dumbledore's sister Ariana, who appears to have some form of PTSD (or similar) disorder from being tormented by other children.

> They forced their way through the hedge,
>   and when she couldn’t show them the trick, they got a bit carried
>   away trying to stop the little freak doing it.
>   ‘It destroyed her, what they did: she was never right again. She
>   wouldn’t use magic, but she couldn’t get rid of it: it turned
>   inwards and drove her mad, it exploded out of her when she
>   couldn’t control it, and at times she was strange and dangerous.
>   But mostly she was sweet, and scared, and harmless.'

Answer (score 2):

About having more than wand: Yes. At the end of *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Harry Potter had **three** wands:

- His own
- Draco Malfoy's
- The Elder Wand

And also, Draco Malfoy also had two wands:

- His own
- The Elder Wand

About whether a mentally ill person would have two wands: Probably not. They might have a highly volatile wand, if they have a wand at all (I can't imagine that someone in their right mind would take a psycho person to buy a wand), but they probably would not have a wand for each personality.

Comment: But was that anything to do with him being mentally ill, as specified in the question?

Answer (score 1):

**We do not know.** There are no characters shown within canon to have a diagnosed mental condition.

There are a few character we with some signs of mental distress... None of them have their wands.

---

**Frank and Alice Longbottom**

Tortured into insanity beyond any cure. They are being treated in St. Mungo's.

---

**Gilderoy Lockhart**

Had his entire memory wiped from a backfiring charm. He is being treated St. Mungo's

---

**Ariana Dumbledore**

Is suffering from sort of mental distress due to the death of her mother. She was not sent to St. Mungo's, but did not have a wand to begin with.