# Can more than one wand suit a wizard?

Tags: harry-potter

Since witches and wizards can get new wands if their old wands break, does that mean that their personalities change?

So that means that 2 different wands suited a certain wizard at different points in time (one wand chooses the wizard when they're 11, assuming it's from Ollivander's, and the other wand after the first wand is broken, lost, or irreparable).

Comment: Seems very dupey to me. The other question specifically addresses this, especially [DVK's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/24379/20774) which highlights a wizard who's been chosen by two different wands only a few years apart.